# Change order of bars and stacks in stacked barplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cptbarplot

I´m trying to graph a series of 11 variables from 5 groups in a stacked barplot. This is my data and code

```
inf_source <- structure(list(inf_episode = c("First", "Second", 
                                     "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"), Pneumonia = c(16,6,2,0,0), 
                        IAI = c(6,2,0,0,0), SSTI = c(7,0,2,0,0), Bacteremia = c(4,14,8,6,2),
                        Sinusitis =c(14,10,0,0,0), Other =c(8,7,7,4,0),
                        UTI=c(14,13,1,0,0), CDI=c(0,0,3,0,2), Dental=c(1,3,1,0,0), 
                        Colitis=c(2,2,1,0,0), CLABSI=c(0,0,3,0,0)), 
                   .Names = c("inf_episode", "Pneumonia", "IAI", "SSTI", 
                              "Bacteremia", "Sinusitis", "Other", "UTI", "CDI", "Dental", "Colitis", "CLABSI"), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L))

inf_source$inf_episode <- factor(inf_source$inf_episode,
                        levels = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"))

inf_source$inf_episode <- reorder(inf_source$inf_episode, rowSums(inf_source[-1]))

md <- melt(inf_source, id=(c("inf_episode")))

ggplot(data = md, aes(x = reorder(inf_episode, value, sum), y = value, fill = variable)) +
geom_col()
```

The graph I got is this:

[image]

The bars start with "Fifth" and end with "First", and I cannot change them to start with "First" and finish with "Fifth". Also, I would like to add the number of time each variable appears in every group, and if possible, the stack size to reflect the number. Any ideas?

I have tried reordering the groups but it´s not working.

Comment: You are using this for your x: `reorder(inf_episode, value, sum)`. If you want them the other way, use the decreasing argument :`reorder(inf_episode, value, sum, decreasing = TRUE)`. Alternatively, order by negative value `reorder(inf_episode, -value, sum)`

Comment: what do you mean with : the stack size to reflect the number.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifically `reorder`ing the factors such that Fifth is the first level. Try this instead. Making sure to set `ordered = TRUE` when calling `factor()`.

You can add text to each bar using `after_stat` by applying a function used by stat. In this case `summary()`, then pass in the `sum` function to your aes call.

```
inf_source$inf_episode <- factor(inf_source$inf_episode, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"))

# inf_source$inf_episode <- reorder(inf_source$inf_episode, rowSums(inf_source[-1]))

md <- melt(inf_source, id=(c("inf_episode")))

ggplot(data = md, aes(x = inf_episode, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(y), group = inf_episode), 
    stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `ggplot` cares about factors being ordered or not.

Comment: Hmm it seems to respect any ordering I use. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I mean that you don't need to set `ordered = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factor with levels!

(I see i am late to the party: )

```
ggplot(data = md,
       aes(x = factor(inf_episode,level=c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth")),
           y = value,
           fill = variable))+
        geom_col()+
        geom_text(aes(label=value),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

This is not a perfect annotation (0 values ) but should get you started.